# Room migration fails on complex schema changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to update room database
want to add two columns with an existing database and don't want to lose the data.

My existing table name WordTable

```
@Entity
data class WordTable(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var word: String = "",
    var des: String = "",
    var bookmark: Boolean = false,
    var addByUser: Boolean = false,
    var uploaded: Boolean = false)
```

I want to add this two column, so my code is now

```
@Entity
data class WordTable(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var word: String = "",
    var des: String = "",
    var ref: String = "Added by user",
    var recent: Date = Date(),
    var bookmark: Boolean = false,
    var addByUser: Boolean = false,
    var uploaded: Boolean = false)
```

Note: I provide date conveter

Create a new table

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    " word TEXT," +
                    " des TEXT," +
                    " ref TEXT," +
                    " recent INTEGER," +
                    " bookmark INTEGER," +
                    " addByUser INTEGER," +
                    " uploaded INTEGER)")
```

Copy previous data

```
database.execSQL("Insert Into USER (id, word, des, bookmark, addByUser, uploaded) Select * From WordTable")
```

Drop word table

```
database.execSQL("Drop Table WordTable")
```

Rename user table to WordTable

```
database.execSQL("Alter Table USER RENAME TO WordTable")
```

And I get this error;

```
Expected:
TableInfo{name='WordTable', columns={addByUser=Column{name='addByUser', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, word=Column{name='word', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, bookmark=Column{name='bookmark', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, uploaded=Column{name='uploaded', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, ref=Column{name='ref', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, des=Column{name='des', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, recent=Column{name='recent', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
Found:
TableInfo{name='WordTable', columns={addByUser=Column{name='addByUser', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, word=Column{name='word', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, bookmark=Column{name='bookmark', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, uploaded=Column{name='uploaded', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1}, ref=Column{name='ref', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, des=Column{name='des', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, recent=Column{name='recent', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

The difference between Expected and Found is

```
Expected: notNull=true
Found: notNull=false
```

so I try to modify the create table code

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `USER` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `word` TEXT NOT NULL, `des` TEXT NOT NULL, `ref` TEXT NOT NULL, `recent` INTEGER NOT NULL, `bookmark` INTEGER NOT NULL, `addByUser` INTEGER NOT NULL, `uploaded` INTEGER NOT NULL)")
```

But this time I get this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: USER.ref (Sqlite code 1299), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:742)
```

I also try alter table and column but get same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy queries to create tables or modify tables from the generated room database file.

Just double tap shift and look for _Impl.

Your problem is related to `NON NULL` data types in your tables you need to specify these fields as `NON NULL` and handle `DEFAULT` values that need to be assigned during your Room Migration.

Comment: I also copied from impl file, but getting same error,

Comment: Can u update question so as to show me your database schema and newly added entities from one version to another?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ALTER TABLE` Query and simply provide migration

```
private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD COLUMN `column_name` {type} DEFAULT {defaultValue} NOT NULL");
        }
    };
```

When you try to Alter Table, then you should provide default values to all other records that are already present in the table.

Comment: alter table is not available in earlier versions of sqlite, which still constitute most of the market as of the time of writing

Answer (score 0):

The differences between Expected and Found in your error message are the not null constraints in your table.

If you want the rows to be nullable, define their variables as objects without default values and make a constructor that defines the required rows. Do not instantiate row values at the same time as you instantiate the variables!

If you want the rows to never accept Null, add NOT NULL to the end of the rows in your SQLite query, and you don't have to change your model class.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need crate new table 
create an method like:

```
  private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
            @Override
            public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                   database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `WordTable` ADD COLUMN ref STRING");
            }
        };
```

and call Database create method like:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(/*parameter want */).addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
```

Comment: I tried this, but I found the last error as I mentioned on the question.